# Objects gets empty in VueJS Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to build an application in `VueJS` where I'm having a component something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <base-subheader title="Members" icon="la-home" heading="Member Details" description="Home"></base-subheader>
        <div class="m-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-6">
                    <nits-form-portlet
                            title="Add Member/User"
                            info="Fill the details below to add user, fields which are mandatory are label with * (star) mark."
                            headIcon="flaticon-multimedia"
                            headerLine
                            apiUrl="api/user"
                            backUrl="members__home"
                            action="create"
                            :formElements="form_elements"
                    >
                    </nits-form-portlet>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "member-add",
        data() {
            return {
                form_elements: [
                    {
                        field_name: 'first_name',
                        config_elements: {
                            label: 'First Name *',
                            type: 'text',
                            inputStyle: 'pill',
                            placeholder: 'Enter first name of user',
                            formControl: true,
                            addonType: 'left-icon',
                            addon: {leftAddon: 'la-exclamation'},
                        },
                        value: '',
                        nitsFormType: 'nits-input'
                    },
                    {
                        field_name: 'last_name',
                        config_elements: {
                            label: 'Last Name',
                            type: 'text',
                            inputStyle: 'pill',
                            placeholder: 'Enter last name of user',
                            formControl: true,
                            addonType: 'left-icon',
                            addon: {leftAddon: 'la-exclamation'},
                        },
                        value: '',
                        nitsFormType: 'nits-input'
                    },
                    {
                        field_name: 'email',
                        config_elements: {
                            label: 'Email *',
                            type: 'email',
                            inputStyle: 'pill',
                            placeholder: 'Enter email of user',
                            formControl: true,
                            addonType: 'left',
                            addon: {leftAddon: '@'},
                        },
                        value: '',
                        nitsFormType: 'nits-input'
                    },
                    {
                        field_name: 'password',
                        config_elements: {
                            label: 'Password *',
                            type: 'password',
                            inputStyle: 'pill',
                            placeholder: 'Enter password',
                            formControl: true,
                            addonType: 'left-icon',
                            addon: {leftAddon: 'la-expeditedssl'},
                        },
                        value: '',
                        nitsFormType: 'nits-input'
                    },
                    {
                        field_name: 'confirm_password',
                        config_elements: {
                            label: 'Confirm Password *',
                            type: 'password',
                            inputStyle: 'pill',
                            placeholder: 'Confirm password should match',
                            formControl: true,
                            addonType: 'left-icon',
                            addon: {leftAddon: 'la-expeditedssl'},
                        },
                        value: '',
                        nitsFormType: 'nits-input'
                    },
                    {
                        field_name: 'role',
                        config_elements: {
                            label: 'Select Role *',
                            inputStyle: 'pill',
                            options: [
                                {option: 'Select one'},
                                {value: '1', option: 'Admin'},
                                {value: '2', option: 'Subscriber'},
                                {value: '3', option: 'Analyst'},
                                {value: '4', option: 'Guest'}
                            ],
                            addonType: 'left-icon',
                            addon: {leftAddon: 'la-user-secret'},
                        },
                        value: '',
                        nitsFormType: 'nits-select'
                    },
                    {
                        field_name: 'profile_pic',
                        config_elements: {
                            label: 'Profile pic',
                        },
                        value: '',
                        nitsFormType: 'nits-file-input'
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Whenever I try to pass data to my component `config_elements` which holds an object of all attributes being passed to child component gets lost, if I move from other component to `nits-form-portlet>` it renders the child components appropriately, but in my `Vue-debug tool` it shows empty:

[image]

But the components are rendered properly:

[image]

And same happens to the props inside the component:

[image]

But in case of any event or refreshing the page it shows:

[image]

Since all the attributes are gone, if I try to configure my `config_elements` object data, I get the attributes but within a fraction of seconds it again goes to empty. But attributes gets passed and it displays the fields:

[image]

I am using render function to render these components so for `nits-form-portlet` component I have:

```
return createElement('div', { class: this.getClasses() }, [
    createElement('div', { class: 'm-portlet__head' }, [
        createElement('div', { class: 'm-portlet__head-caption' }, [element])
    ]),
    createElement('form', { class: 'm-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right' }, [
        createElement('div', { class: 'm-portlet__body' }, [
            createElement('div', { class: 'form-group m-form__group m--margin-top-10' }, [infoElement]),
            this.computedFormElements.map(a => {
                if(this.error[a.field_name]) {
                    a.config_elements.error = this.error[a.field_name][0];
                    return createElement(a.nitsFormType, { attrs: a.config_elements, on: {
                        input: (event) => {
                            this.form[a.field_name] = event
                        }
                    }})
                }
                else
                    return createElement(a.nitsFormType, { attrs: a.config_elements, on: {
                        input: (event) => {
                            this.form[a.field_name] = event
                        }
                    }})
            })
        ]),
        footerElement
    ])
])
```

And I think factors affecting the template is this map statement:

```
this.computedFormElements.map(a => {
    if(this.error[a.field_name]) {
        a.config_elements.error = this.error[a.field_name][0];
        return createElement(a.nitsFormType, { attrs: a.config_elements, on: {
            input: (event) => {
                this.form[a.field_name] = event
            }
        }})
    }
    else
        return createElement(a.nitsFormType, { attrs: a.config_elements, on: {
            input: (event) => {
                this.form[a.field_name] = event
            }
        }})
})
```

but still I'm sharing my whole code of render function, [Link to code @ github](https://github.com/noeticit/nitseditor/blob/master/resources/assets/js/Components/Admin/Elements/Portlets/_nits_form_portlet.js) hoping someone can help me with this strange situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell for me without running the code, but I've noticed something that may be related.

I see that you're overwriting the `formElements` prop here:

`a.config_elements.error = this.error[a.field_name][0];`

Vue usually gives you a warning that you can't do that, but maybe because it's abstracted through the computed it's not doing so.

If you want to extend the data for use in the child component, then it's best to do copy of the object (preferably a deep copy using computed, which will allow you to have it dynamically updated)

because `config_elements` is an object, when you add `error` variable you are likely triggering an observer, that may be clearing the data in the parent.

Anyway, it's just a guess, but something you may want to resolve anyway.